# When is network-manager-openvpn going to be updated to the 0.9 version?

Tags: network-manager, openvpn

Since bug [274930](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=274930) implemented added functionalities in Network Manager regarding OpenVPN, the network-manager-openvpn plugin needs to be updated to **0.9** version to benefit from those improvements.
At the moment, with the ***0.899*** version it is impossible to connect to a openvpn server; the following is generated in the syslog file:

```
Sep 11 09:25:38 abc NetworkManager[1594]: <info> Starting VPN service 'openvpn'...
Sep 11 09:25:38 abc NetworkManager[1594]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn), PID 5083
Sep 11 09:25:38 abc NetworkManager[1594]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' appeared; activating connections
Sep 11 09:25:38 abc NetworkManager[1594]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: 1
Sep 11 09:25:38 abc NetworkManager[1594]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: 3
Sep 11 09:25:38 abc NetworkManager[1594]: <info> VPN connection 'XYZ' (Connect) reply received.
Sep 11 09:25:38 abc NetworkManager[1594]: <warn> VPN connection 'XYZ' failed to connect: 'property 'user-name' invalid or not supported'.
Sep 11 09:25:38 abc NetworkManager[1594]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
Sep 11 09:25:38 abc NetworkManager[1594]: <info> Policy set 'Auto eth0' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Sep 11 09:25:43 abc NetworkManager[1594]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' disappeared
```

When will it be updated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming there are no last minute regressions, these package ARE v0.9.

As you can see from the [change-logs](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openvpn/0.8.999-1ubuntu1) (at the time of writing this), release candidate 2 is being used from upstream.

It is usual for the developers and maintainers to use either the full release-candidate versions from upstream - or to cherry pick certain bugfixes and merge this in.  In this case, the maintainers are using the release-candidate version + some alternate compile options.

So - as to your issue - I would strongly recommend you file a bug-report on launchpad to help the maintainers find a solution before v0.9 is fully committed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply; do you have a specific link concerning network-manager packages so that I can link a bug report to it?

Comment: I think you would just type `ubuntu-bug network-manager-openvpn` to report this on launchpad - obviously make sure you have a launchpad account first :)

Comment: OK, I filled bug [848014](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openvpn/+bug/848014)

Comment: Last minute update: network-manager-openvpn plugin v0.9 has just been released; however it did not solve my issue.  After further investigation, I found out that in the config file for my OpenVPN connexion (located in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections) the entry **user-name** should be **username**. The old syntax was handled and generated by the previous version of the plugin (I upgraded my system from 10.04 to 11.10 beta). I hope this will help someone else ...

Comment: @softexpert why not make that a new question and an answer ;)